# In my html nav bar. my bar sticks to the left of the margin. How do I remedy this?

Tags: html, css, nav

When I use notepad++ it works just fine. But when using asp.net wep app in VS it does this:

[Image of Nav](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7AAo.png)

The nav bar just sticks out even though the margin is set to 0.

Is there something by default in visual studio that does this?
Thanks in advance!

Here is the HTML and CSS:

```css
body {
    margin: 0 0 55px 0;
}

.nav {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 55px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background-color: #ffffff;
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.nav__link {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-grow: 1;
    min-width: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #444444;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    transition: background-color 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

    .nav__link:hover {
        background-color: #eeeeee;
    }

.nav__link--active {
    color: #009578;
}

.nav__icon {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Bottom Nav Bar

    </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device=width, initial scale=1.0" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/favicon.ico">
    <link href="/assets/favicon.ico" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/nav.css">

</head>

<body>
 
    <nav class="nav">
    <a href="#" class="nav__link">
        <i class="material-icons nav__icon">dashboard</i>
        <span class="nav__text">Dashboard</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="nav__link nav__link--active">
        <i class="material-icons nav__icon">person</i>
        <span class="nav__text">Profile</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="nav__link">
        <i class="material-icons nav__icon">devices</i>
        <span class="nav__text">Devices</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="nav__link">
        <i class="material-icons nav__icon">lock</i>
        <span class="nav__text">Privacy</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="nav__link">
        <i class="material-icons nav__icon">settings</i>
        <span class="nav__text">Settings</span>
    </a>
</nav>

</body>


</html>
```

As you can tell I've entered html as well. For some reason It wasn't letting me do so. Does anyone understand why this isnt working?

Comment: Hi Can you post your HTML as well? thanks
!

Comment: Hi John,I just did, and posted the picture.

Comment: Is this really your HTML code? The first part (opening `<nav>` tag and link to "Dashboard") is repeated (?)

Comment: The HTML is from codepen. Trying to implement google fonts and icons for a nav bar. Like I said it works with notepad++ but not VS. Yeah i just saw that.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it, but try adding `left:0;` to `.nav`, so it looks like:

```
.nav {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 55px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background-color: #ffffff;
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```